# AsyncStorage is failing when integrating with web-app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, sdk, asyncstorage

Currently we are building an app with react-native and fetching data such as login/signup etc handled within X-sdk we built.
Basically, what X-sdk is a middleware/api fetcher that communicates with back-end api and gets data for us.
To make app-development more simpler we handled token storing in the sdk using react-native/async-storage dependency. The issue is it is failing when we integrate sdk with web-app since it is not compatible with web-apps.

Is there any way to store the token locally for both app(react-native) and web-app.

Answer (score 0):

react-native/async-storage dependency apply only react native if you want to use hlocalstorage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).